# First post review queue: answers are questions, questions are answers

Tags: bug, status-completed, review

I believe there is a typo in the ["first post"](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts) review queue. When reviewing a question, the information message asks the user to review the *answer*. Take a look at the image below.

[image: Question called an answer.]

Similarly, when an answer is posted in the queue, the description box calls it a question instead. Has anyone else noticed this?

Comment: It is meant to keep you awake! :D

Comment: @AshishNitinPatil I was thinking the same thing. The developers were carefully timing us to see who notices the *intended* typos first.

Comment: Damn, as if audits weren't confusing enough already, now even non-audits bear fake information :-)

Comment: @JanDvorak lol… yes I stumbled on this too, luckily I thought to search for “review” on meta before asking (got at least 2 dups already). I think they just got the texts mixed. Should be dead easy to fix.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We've recently ported *all* of the review queue view rendering stuff into proper cshtml razor views. This included *denormalizing* a lot of sentence building *code* into *full sentences*, which is the only way to get correct translations for them (because of [declension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Declension) and for starters).

Should be fixed in next build `2013.12.23.1804` on meta and `2013.12.23.1264`.

Comment: I was recently told to talk about SE websites in the plural. I declined.

Comment: @KerrekSB there can be only ones!